# Mysql- syntax to use near '' at line 1

Tags: php, mysql

Hi guys here's my code I've faced with such error:
"""You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1"""

```
    <?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(!$con){
die('could not connect' .mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("phptest",$con);

$insert="INSERT INTO persons (FirstName,LastName)VALUES('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]'";
if(!mysql_query($insert,$con))
{
    die('error:' .mysql_error());
}
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

simple code but I don't know where's wrong....

Comment: You forgot to close `VALUES`, voting to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You forgot the closing `)` in your statement

   ```
   INSERT INTO persons (FirstName,LastName)
   VALUES('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]')
   ```

   and
2. You need to escape your user input

   - To avoid syntax errors in your query
   - and SQL injections

   Use *Prepared Statements* for that

Comment: This should be chosen as the answer because not only does it solve the issue OP was having, but it tells OP that they are vulnerable to SQL injection and how to solve that.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct this syntax as follwoing
`$insert="INSERT INTO persons (FirstName,LastName)VALUES('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]')"`;

Answer (score 0):

You have not closed the Bracket that you opened TO INSERT VALUES. You are missing `)` .Close this bracket and use the code as follows

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(!$con){
die('could not connect' .mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("phptest",$con);

$insert="INSERT INTO persons (FirstName,LastName)VALUES('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]')";
if(!mysql_query($insert,$con))
{
    die('error:' .mysql_error());
}
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

I should advice you to not use user input for inserting the data. This can make the task easier for the hackers to hack your sql and that is by sql injection.

**SQL Injection: What is it?**

SQL Injection is one of the many web attack mechanisms used by hackers to steal data from organizations. It is perhaps one of the most common application layer attack techniques used today. It is the type of attack that takes advantage of improper coding of your web applications that allows hacker to inject SQL commands into say a login form to allow them to gain access to the data held within your database.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing `)`

```
$insert="INSERT INTO persons (FirstName,LastName)VALUES('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]')";
```